# Пробелма сз апуском eclipse

Tags: eclipse

По не понятной причине перестал запускаться eclipse. Не запускается само приложение, не выдает ошибку. Переустановка не дала никакого результата. Все равно не запускается. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Уточните хотя бы ОС.

Comment: Установлено Windows, работаю на терминалке,на вирт машине

Comment: может быть связано c версией java, наличием в системе двух версий java

Comment: Просмотрел path и в пути написано C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\client. А мне нужно ссылаться на jre1.8.0_141\bin. Добавил чрез командную сроку, но новый путь просто добавился в конце. Как можно заменить путь где прописано к jre6 на jre1.8.0_141?